# Как в bash-скрипте вызвать последнюю команду или аргумент?

Tags: bash, консоль, скрипт, sh

При работе с терминалом **`bash`** можно повторять предыдущую команду или подставить аргумент из последней команды, используя специальную последовательность при вводе:

```bsh
echo 'Arg 1' 'Arg 2' 'Arg 3'
!! 
echo !:3
```

результат интерпретации терминалом:

```bsh
echo 'Arg 1' 'Arg 2' 'Arg 3'
echo 'Arg 1' 'Arg 2' 'Arg 3'
echo 'Arg 3'
```

Однако в bash-скрипте такие последовательности ( `!!`, `!:1`, etc…) не работают.

Существуют ли способы в потоке выполнения **`bash`** скрипта записанного в файл `.sh` обращаться к предыдущим командам и их аргументам?

Comment: Посмотрите man bash по слову history. Но никакого особого смысла я не вижу. В скрипте можно и переменную написать

Answer (score 4):

В скриптах, история выключена по-умолчанию. Для того, чтобы включить, используйте это:

```
set -o history -o histexpand
```

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run#9502698)

PS. Также выключены алиасы. Чтобы включить:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias la='ls -la'
la
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто используй переменные:

```
ARG3='Arg 3'
ARG_CMD=(echo 'Arg 1' 'Arg 2' "$ARG3")
"${ARG_CMD[@]}"
"${ARG_CMD[@]}"
echo "$ARG3"
```